# Rails 5.2 Active Storage add custom attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I have a model with attachments:

```rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :images
end
```

When I attach and save the image I also want to save an additional custom attribute - `display_order` (integer) with the attached image. I want to use it to sort the attached images and display them in the order I specified in this custom attribute. I've reviewed ActiveStorage source code for `#attach` method as well as `ActiveStorage::Blob` model but it looks like there is no built in method to pass some custom metadata.

I wonder, what's the idiomatic way to solve this problem with ActiveStorage? In the past I would usually just add a `display_order` attribute to the ActiveRecord model which represents my attachment and then simply use it with `.order(display_order: :asc)` query.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you need to store additional data with each image and perform queries based on that data, I’d recommend extracting an `Image` model that wraps an attached `file`:

```
# app/models/project.rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
# app/models/image.rb
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project

  has_one_attached :file
  delegate_missing_to :file

  scope :positioned, -> { order(position: :asc) }
end
```

```
<%# app/views/projects/show.html.erb %>
<% @project.images.positioned.each do |image| %>
  <%= image_tag image %>
<% end %>
```

Note that the example view above causes 2N+1 queries for a project with N images (one query for the project’s images, another for each image’s `ActiveStorage::Attachment` record, and one more for each attached `ActiveStorage::Blob`). I deliberately avoided optimizing the number of queries for clarity’s sake.

Comment: Is there any efficient way to use the "with_attached_#{}" macro using this solution?

Comment: @Richard, you can use `ActiveRecord::Base#includes` and `#merge` to define your own `with_attached_images` scope. Here’s a fuller example: https://gist.github.com/georgeclaghorn/9baf3b9f1796eed5a983d35825b7f86c

Comment: Thank you so much for the example, will try this tomorrow!

Comment: Hi @GeorgeClaghorn.  I just stumbled upon this post investigating similar needs.  I have implemented user rotate and crop functionality.  In order for it to work, those values need to be saved in the db and called by active storage on render.  Is saving additional attributes with an attachment a possible feature in future active storage versions?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to order the images, you could customize the filename and order the images by filename. I use the down gem which I highly recommend.

For example:

```
image = Down.download(image_url)
filename = "description-#{order}"
@object.images.attach(io: image, filename: filename)
```

then in your controller for @object:

```
@images = @object.images_attachments.joins(:blob).order('active_storage_blobs.filename ASC')
```

then in your view for @object

```
<%@images.each do |image|%>
<%= image_tag image%>
<% end %>
```